# How to change home page url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am going to change home page in wordpress. so I created new page and I am going to change the homepage to new page. but I can't change it.
How to solve its problem?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to choose page in settings -> writting (I think this is in english) and choose you cover page

[image]